# Using multicore Mac in R through console

Tags: r, macos, multicore

This is my first question ever in StackOverflow, so please excuse me if I do any mistake, or if my question is too basic.

I am performing clustering with R version 3.3.0 "Supposedly Educational" and I would like to use **multicore** in my **MacBook Pro**. I have read throughout many articles regarding calling multicore using `parallel` package, as well as `%dopar%`, but I understand that:

1st. This is for script writing instead of console (I use workspace directly from console).

2nd. Actually, I **would love that every action performed in R is made using the two cores of my laptop**, from importing csv files (with 24 variables and 300000 rows), to calculating `for` loops, etc. If that's possible, of course. That would save me some time, I think; I am not a computing expert.

Thank you all for reading.

Comment: For the first point, it works fine in console, it is common for scripting because multi threading is of most benefit for huge jobs. For the second, multi threading has a calculation overhead cost and actually slows down small jobs. For reading in big tables try `data.table`'s `fread` function.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's slow or not working that is requiring delving into parallelism? That's not an especially large CSV file and both reading and ML ops over it shld be fairly performant unless you have an super-old or under-config'd MBPro.

Comment: It's a 2009 Intel Core 2 Duo MBP.